# Make directory of Docker container readable on host

Tags: docker, permissions, filesystems

I am using an existing Dockerfile. That one manages directories of the Docker container under a user `docker` with UID 5000.

I am mapping a directory of the container to a host directory.

Given that I am not able to modify the original Dockerfile, how could I gain read access to this directory? I tried

```
sudo chmod -R +r dir/
```

But it only lead to corrupting the permissions of the parent directory, i.e. on `ls -lshr` I was getting

```
? d????????? ? ? ? ?            ?
```

What other options are there?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't corrupted the permissions, they just (somewhat confusingly) work differently for directories than for files.

You need to also give yourself execute permission to be able to access a directory.

See [this related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252) for more information.